# How to select data based on 2 conditions in R?

Tags: r, if-statement, bioinformatics

I am looking to select a subset of my data based on 2 conditions:

Firstly, here is my data:

```
Gene           AreaID   Label
DNAJC12      rs1111111  unlikely
HERC4        rs1111111  unlikely
RP11-57G10.8 rs2222222  possible
RPL12P8      rs1111111  unlikely
SIRT1        rs3333333  certain
RP11-57G10.8 rs3333333  possible
RPL12P8      rs3333333  unlikely
SIRT1        rs3333333  unlikely
```

I am looking to subset this to select the genes with an 'unlikely' label and if they have the same area ID. However, the ID must also *not* be present for any other genes with any other label.

So for example my output would only select this:

```
Gene          AreaID      Label
DNAJC12     rs1111111   unlikely
HERC4       rs1111111   unlikely
RPL12P8     rs1111111   unlikely
```

and not include the `rs333333` area ID which has unlikely with duplicate IDs but also has genes of different labels.

Essentially I am looking to subset for the areas which only have genes labelled as unlikely.

I have tried based on reading similar questions on here, but this does not seems to work:

```
loci <- read.csv('dataset.csv')
sub_list <- lapply(1:length(loci), function(i) loci %>% filter(loci$AreaID==duplicated(loci) & loci$Label =='unlikely'))
do.call(rbind, sub_list)
```

I have also tried:

```
prediction_snps = loci$AreaID[loci$label == 'unlikely']
result = loci[prediction_snps, ]
```

I am not sure how else to approach this as I am new to R, currently

Comment: Don't use `$` inside `dplyr` functions.

Comment: `duplicated` returns `TRUE` or `FALSE`, so `AreaID==duplicated(loci)` is testing whether `AreaID` is TRUE when `loci` is duplicated and `FALSE` when `loci` is unique (or the first occurrence). Since `AreaID` isn't T/F, this won't work. (Just trying to help you understand why your attempt didn't work.)

Comment: Thank you for this, I tried reading about the function but didnt find my resource very clear, so this helps a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*group_by* `AreaID` then filter where all `Label` equal to "unlikely"

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(AreaID) %>% filter(all(Label=="unlikely"))

# A tibble: 3 x 3
  # Groups:   AreaID [1]
  Gene    AreaID    Label   
  <chr>   <chr>     <chr>   
  1 DNAJC12 rs1111111 unlikely
  2 HERC4   rs1111111 unlikely
  3 RPL12P8 rs1111111 unlikely
```

Answer (score 1):

We can try

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
    filter(AreaID != "rs3333333") %>% 
    filter(Label == "unlikely")
#    Gene    AreaID    Label
#1 DNAJC12 rs1111111 unlikely
#2   HERC4 rs1111111 unlikely
#3 RPL12P8 rs1111111 unlikely
```

---

Or it could be also

```
df1 %>%  group_by(AreaID) %>% filter(first(Label) ==  "unlikely")
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Unfortunately, whilst this output gives only unlikely genes, it still gives those which have an Area ID shared with the other differently labelled genes in my original data

Comment: @DN1  Can you check the output now

Comment: Thank you, the first one works for just the example dataset. Unfortunately my data is much bigger and I can't know the area IDs to set in the first filter. The second solution also gives me the output similar to my first comment. However, I will try to work from the first example you've given and see if I can get what I need, so thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In *base* you could get a *subset for the areas which only have genes labelled as unlikely* with:

```
loci <- read.table(header = TRUE, text="Gene           AreaID   Label
DNAJC12      rs1111111  unlikely
HERC4        rs1111111  unlikely
RP11-57G10.8 rs2222222  possible
RPL12P8      rs1111111  unlikely
SIRT1        rs3333333  certain
RP11-57G10.8 rs3333333  possible
RPL12P8      rs3333333  unlikely
SIRT1        rs3333333  unlikely")

#Get AreaID where all are labelled unlikely
tt <- aggregate(cbind(all=Label=="unlikely") ~ AreaID, data=loci, FUN=all)

#Merge with those AreaID's to get Genes
merge(loci, tt[tt$all,]["AreaID"])

#     AreaID    Gene    Label
#1 rs1111111 DNAJC12 unlikely
#2 rs1111111   HERC4 unlikely
#3 rs1111111 RPL12P8 unlikely
```

Comment: Thank you for this, unfortunately with the first line setting tt I am getting: ```Error in `[.data.frame`(with(unique(loci), aggregate(cbind(n = rep(1,  : 
  undefined columns selected```

Comment: Thank you this has no errors and selects only genes with unlikely labels, but unfortunately still selects those with an AreaID which is also shared with genes of other labels, but thank you I will try to expand from this.